# Typescript Unit Testing File Structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, typescript

I want to make typescript unit tests and I am having a lot of trouble with the file structure regarding module inputs. I am using the node typescript plugin and typescript 2.0.10.

My file structure is as follows:

```
+ app
  |
  + models
    |
    +user.js
+ test
  |
  + app
    |
    + models
      |
      +user.js
+ src
  |
  + app
  | |
  | + models
  | | |
  | | + user.ts
  | + tsconfig.json
  + test
    |
    + app
      |
      + models
      | |
      | + user.ts
      + tsconfig.json
```

`/app` and `/test` contain the transpiled JavaScript for executing.

`/src/app/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "filesGlob": ["./**/*.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "../../public/"
  }
}
```

`/src/test/app/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "filesGlob": ["./**/*.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "../../../test/app/"
  }
}
```

This transpiles fine into the file structure. The problem is when I import from the actual models in the test I need 3 parent directories but in the final JavaScript I only need 2 parent directories. I have tried `baseUrl` and `paths`, which is why I am using typescript 2.0.10. They either did nothing or made it compile into a test directory inside the test directory in a very convoluted nested file structure that also broke it. How should I structure this transpiling and testing? Is there a better way to structure these files? I know I could use require instead of import to get rid of the error from typescript and import based on the JavaScript directory but then I won't be able to use the typescript plugin to see the types of what I am testing.

Here is what I tried with `baseUrl` and `paths`. This was in `/src/test/app/tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions`:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths":  {
  "models": "../../../app/models"
},
```

Update: I can make it work by using the same configuration file for all of src. I am still curious if there is a better way to do this.